# Movesense : Is it possible to connect to 3 or more sensors?

Tags: android, movesense

I have edited the multi-connection example (android) to connect to 3 movesense devices. But I am able to connect to only 2. The log messages show that the app keeps trying to establish a connection with the third sensor, but the connection does not go through. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

With earlier Android examples, device versions I could connect 4 sensors. There were some changes needed in connection logic to go beyond 2 sensors. If I remember correctly I separated connection calls

```
...
Mds.builder().build(MultiConnectionActivity.this).connect(mRxBleDevice1.getMacAddress(), null);
Mds.builder().build(MultiConnectionActivity.this).connect(mRxBleDevice2.getMacAddress(), null);
Mds.builder().build(MultiConnectionActivity.this).connect(mRxBleDevice3.getMacAddress(), null);
...
```

to point of selection of each device. Anyway above three consecutive calls as such didn't work for me either.